# Luis: How to have a generic entity that matches any word

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Suppose I have a intent "findStuff" that takes things of the form

- find xxx
- list xxx where something = somevalue
- find xxx where something = somevalue

Getting the LUIS to understand that "xxx" is any word seems hard. I defined a "plainWord" entity, and defined a pattern feature with the same name & value "\w+".  I thought that that used to work, but doesn't seem to be doing it any more.  Some words that it has seen it recognizes, but it can never seem to deal with "find junk" -- "junk" is never recognized as any entity.

The system for which this is intended is open-ended.  Users can add there own types of things that we may "find."...

Answer (score 0):

How extensively trained is your model? You should update your model by labeling users' utterances. I recommend against using generalized entities like a "plainWord" entity, from your description it sounds like this entity is supposed to just be applied to words that occur after "find" and "list". If an entity has not been labeled/applied to many utterances, your model will not catch the words you want it to catch.

If you post your LUIS model I might be able to better help you. You can export the JSON model or provide your application ID to share it.